# Keeping other variables when using by statement, head, n=1 in R

Tags: r

i have a list of 48000 obs and 6 variables. I am getting the heighest value for each combination of 3 variables.

```
rankout1<- by(r1$ARL_method1, r1[, c('nphase1', 'meanshift', 'Sigmashift')],head,n=1)
rankout2<- by(r2$ARL_method2, r2[, c('nphase1', 'meanshift', 'Sigmashift')],head,n=1)
```

This outputs the list of 48 obs i am looking for. This method only outputs the ARL values for these 48 obs i am trying to capture, but i need the other variables along with the arl_method1. i tried creating a data frame between the large dataset and the small set but because of the obvious different in rows the data set cant be combined. So im looking to output the (meanshift, sigashift, and nphase1) values of those 48 observations along with the ARL value.

```
rankout1<-do.call("rbind", as.list(rankout1))
rankout2<-do.call("rbind", as.list(rankout2))
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: with `dplyr` you could do something like `your_data %>% group_by(nphase1, meanshift, Sigmashift) %>% arrange(desc(variable_to_order)) %>% slice(1)`, but of course without a reproducible example I cannot test my code and then I do not guarantee my code works well.
￼

Answer (score 0):

as @SabDem suggested, I was able to get the set of data i was looking for using Dplyr package.

```
desiredrun<-1/0.0027 

rankout1<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\R\\study2_rank1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
rankout2<-read.table("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\R\\study2_rank2.csv", header=TRUE, sep="")
rankout2<-rankout2[,-4]
r1<-data.frame(rankout1, D1=abs(rankout1$ARL_method1-desiredrun))
r2<-data.frame(rankout2, D2=abs(rankout2$ARL_method2-desiredrun))

r1<-r1[order(r1$nphase1, r1$meanshift, r1$Sigmashift, r1$D1),]
r2<-r2[order(r2$nphase1, r2$meanshift, r2$Sigmashift, r2$D2),]


r1<-r1 %>% group_by(nphase1, meanshift, Sigmashift) %>% arrange(desc(ARL_method1)) %>% slice(1)
r2<-r2 %>% group_by(nphase1, meanshift, sigmashift) %>% arrange(desc(ARL_method2)) %>% slice(1)
```

Comment: You are welcome. Next time provide a piece of your data with `dput` and/or a desired output. I do not want to be wrong but I think that the `order` step is not necessary for achieving your goal.